# Wordpress showing same posts on each page

Tags: php, wordpress

I think it has something to do with the main loop. I don't want to include a category in the main loop so I have done the following.

However, it just shows the most recent posts on each page when I go to the next one in the pagination. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-219'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
        <nav>       
           <div class="pager">
              <div class="pager-btn" id="next-pager"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></div>
              <div class="pager-btn" id="last-pager"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Last' ); ?></div>
           </div>
        </nav>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I've tried changing it to only include the categories I want instead of excluding the one but it still does the same. It works fine if I just include one category though (e.g. I put `cat=1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this to functions.php.

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-219' );
}
return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to make queries with proper arguments, like this:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3 (or -1 for all post),
        'cat'=>219
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then in your loop, you could do this:

```
     if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
      
                    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
     
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
            
          
     
    
                      <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            <nav>       
                               <div class="pager">
                                   <?php if (function_exists("pagination")){pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);} ?>
                               </div>
                            </nav>
      <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Then copy the Pagination Code in functions.php:

```
   function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages)
        {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if(1 != $pages)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
        if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
        {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
            {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
            }
        }

        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

More information you can find at
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. How would this fit in to what I already have?

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately, still go the same issue.

Comment: @K.Mayers can you try with the new code? And share some outputs

Comment: I used the code as you put but it just does the exact same thing. Going to the next page just shows the same posts rather than the actual next page.